# base_path is wrong when deploy laravel in sub directory on apache server

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have a problem when deploy laravel in sub directory on apache server:
First, I have a laravel deployed at DocumentRoot as usual, httpd config:

`DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public"`

Second, I add an alias to deploy another laravel, named `admin` in a sub directory:

```
Alias /admin "/var/www/html/admin/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/admin/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But when I run `composer install` from sub directory: admin, base_path is not correct. It still require files from `/var/www/html/`. It should require files from sub directory `/var/www/html/admin`.
Do I need any more config ?

Comment: So, you have a laravel application inside a laravel application huh?

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya : Thank you for your reply. I will move the 1st application to a sub directory too. Do I need any configuration to correct the base_path ?

Comment: You don't need two laravel applications for what you are trying to do. All you need is one laravel application and with proper `route prefixing`, you can work wonders.